# How can i solve the problem class function is not defined?

Tags: python, function, class

This code is gives me this error:

> self.model = create_model() NameError: name
>
> 'create_model' is not defined

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

class model:
    def __init__(self, algorithm):
        self.algorithm = algorithm
        self.model = create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        if self.algorithm == 'MLPREG':
            return  MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,), activation='relu', solver='adam', random_state=1, max_iter=3000, verbose=True)

def main():
    ex = model('MLPREG')

main()
```

I don't understand, everything looks normal. But I can't run the program.

Comment: `self.model = self.create_model()`

Comment: ov yes, big mistake! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to:

```
class model:
    def __init__(self, algorithm):
        self.algorithm = algorithm
        self.model = self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        if self.algorithm == 'MLPREG':
            return  MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(20,), activation='relu', solver='adam', random_state=1, max_iter=3000, verbose=True)
```